# How to transition from spork to spring?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, spork, rails-spring

I am currently using Spork with Guard, Rspec, and Cucumber. I'd like to move to Spring, but can't find any documentation on what I need to change.

Specifically, I'm curious if I need to change out my:

```
require 'spork'

Spork.prefork do
  # ...
end

Spork.each_run do
  # ...
end
```

...with something like:

```
require 'spring'

Spring.prefork do
  # ...
end

Spring.each_run do
  # ...
end
```

However, I know that [there isn't a `Spring.prefork` because the documentation says so](https://github.com/rails/spring#running-code-before-forking). So should I simply remove the references to `Spork` or do I need to replace them with something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mention in your question, there is no Prefork block. The docs provide a workaround: simply move your existing `Spork.prefork` block to an initializer or anywhere that it will be picked up and run at load time by Rails.

From https://github.com/rails/spring#running-code-before-forking:

> There is no Spring.before_fork callback. To run something before the fork, you can place it in `~/.spring.rb` or `config/spring.rb` or in any of the files which get run when your application initializes, such as `config/application.rb`, `config/environments/*.rb` or `config/initializers/*.rb`.

As for your `Spork.each_run` block, since you're using Rspec you could move it into a `before(:suite)` block. See the Rspec docs on [before and after hooks](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks)

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove all occurrences of `Spork` and install `spring`.

Afterwards run `bundle exec spring binstub --all`.

Now if you run `bin/rails c` it will use `spring`.

For `rspec` use `spring-commands-rspec`